# Django on Apache - Prevent 504 Gateway Timeout

Tags: django, apache, http, httprequest, mod-wsgi

I have a Django server running on Apache via mod_wsgi. I have a massive background task, called via a API call, that searches emails in the background (generally takes a few hours) that is done in the background.

In order to facilitate debugging - as exceptions and everything else happen in the background - I created a API call to run the task blocking. So the browser actually blocks for those hours and receives the results.

In localhost this is fine. However, in the real Apache environment, after about 30 minutes I get a 504 Gateway Timeout error.

How do I change the settings so that Apache allows - just in this debug phase - for the HTTP request to block for a few hours without returning a 504 Gateway Timeout?

I'm assuming this can be changed in the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing long running tasks within Apache processes, nor even waiting for them. Use a background task queueing system such as Celery to run them. Have any web request return as soon as it is queued and implement some sort of polling mechanism as necessary to see if the job is complete and results can be obtained.

Also, are you sure the 504 isn't coming from some front end proxy (explicit or transparent) or load balancer? There is no default timeout in Apache which is 30 minutes.

Comment: Graham, thank you for the input. Using Celery as BG processing is what I already do. Running the task actively versus BG is just for debugging purposes. When running in BG I can save the exception description, but running actively gives me the yellow Django screen with the whole stack description. About the proxy or load balancer, I have no idea. I have the app hosted on a WebFactional hosting account. It's precisely that kind of detail that I need help figuring out.

Comment: Ask on the WebFaction forums what sort of timeout value they have on their front end nginx proxy which sits in front of your Apache. They may well have a really high value such as 30 minutes on that, although it seems to be an excessively large value even to use with nginx.